# Which technology should I use to implement a Java-written WebService, to consume with the apache HttpClient in android?

Tags: android

I would like to create a Java-written RESTFul Web Service, possibly using an eclipse plugin.

This service should be consumed by an android application, using the apache HttpClient.

But my question is, which is the best/ideal technology (server side) to implement this kind of web service?

Comment: I'm finally making all from scratch: Eclipse + Tomcat + Java Servlets. www.restlet.org is also a good alternative and Jersey or Spring too. Tank you for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

[www.restlet.org](http://www.restlet.org), which is also Google App Engine compatible.  I'm using it to implement a RESTful data-transmission service.

Answer (score 1):

If it is going to be something simple you can either use Jersey or Spring and run it on Google App Engine.